# RoboFTP script returning error message

Tags: ftp

I'm attempting to connect to an FTP server via Robo-FTP script using the following command:

FTPLOGON "***myURL***" /trust=ALL /servertype=SFTP /port=22 /user=***myUsername*** /pw=***myPassword***

And I'm receiving the following error message back:

Error: Could not read settings for site ***myURL*** from registry: ServerName: QueryString size failed: The handle is invalid.

Any ideas what this means? I'm able to connect via a regular FTP client.

Comment: That error is a red herring (We fixed the logging on that at a later time). It just means myURL doesn't refer to a managed site definition in the registry. Which is totally fine since you have all the needed site parameters passed as arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out my IP address was banned on the FTP server. Hope this helps anyone in the future.